# change link button text = approve to "APPROVED in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

i have this in my html:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" CommandName="Approve" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

and this is my code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCtrl") as CheckBox);
                LinkButton link = ((LinkButton)GridView1.FindControl("btnApprove"));
                if (chkRow.Checked)
                {
                    using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
                    {
                        scn.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update o set o.Updatedproduct = p.ProductQuantity - o.Totalproduct from CustomerProducts o inner join Products p on o.ProductID = p.ProductID WHERE o.CustomerID=@CustomerID", scn);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[0].Text;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        link.Text = "Approved";
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

what i want to happen is after i click on the `approve link button`, it will perform its function and afterwards will have the link button text changed to approved and if possible, to a read only status.

I have tried doing `link.Enabled` but it seems like its not reading it. `Link.Text="Approved` does not do the trick as well. Any tricks on this? thank you so much

UPDATE:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCtrl") as CheckBox);
                LinkButton link = row.Cells[8].FindControl("btnApprove") as LinkButton;
                if (link != null)
                    link.Text = "Approved";
                if (chkRow.Checked)
                {
                    using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
                    {
                        scn.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update o set o.Updatedproduct = p.ProductQuantity - o.Totalproduct from CustomerProducts o inner join Products p on o.ProductID = p.ProductID WHERE o.CustomerID=@CustomerID", scn);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[0].Text;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //link.Text = "Approved";
                        Label1.Visible = true;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }

                }
```

when i click on the approve link button, it changes all of the texts to approved. it should be the clicked button that will only change. and hopefully it will be permanently changed to approved. thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the status of the link in your database and then on the basis of the values of status field, you need to set the link text as `approve` or `approved`. Using the same status field, you can make it `readonly` too.

So, Modify your database tables and add a new field to the current approval status.

Currently, You are not saving it to database and for this reason when you reload your page, it will be back to original status again.

Hope it helps.

Update:
You have two tables namely `Products` and `CustomerProducts`. You need to alter your table  and add a new column `ApproveStatus` of type bit by running this query.
`Alter table CustomerProducts add ApproveStatus bit null`.
Now, In your select query, you need to include this column `ApproveStatus` and modify your `GridView` code.

Add this code in your code behind class

```
protected string GetApprovalStatus(object value)
{
   if(Convert.ToBoolean(value))
   return "Approved";
   else 
   return "Approve";
}
```

Modify your `GridView` Template for Approve `LinkButton`.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="<%=this.GetApprovalStatus(Eval("ApproveStatus"));%>" CommandName="Approve" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Now, you need to change this line in code behind as:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    bool status = false;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCtrl") as CheckBox);
            LinkButton link = ((LinkButton)GridView1.FindControl("btnApprove"));

            if (chkRow.Checked)
            {

        if(link.Text == "Approved")
        {
            status = true;  
        }
        else
        {
            status = false;
        }
                using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
                {
                    scn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update o set o.Updatedproduct = p.ProductQuantity - o.Totalproduct, o.ApproveStatus = @status from CustomerProducts o inner join Products p on o.ProductID = p.ProductID WHERE o.CustomerID=@CustomerID", scn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[0].Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hmm where do i start sir? what will i add to my database field? and what will i save to the database? thank you so much

Comment: @Rahul, How will you persist the approved status until you save it somewhere (db).

Comment: sir @vivek can you guide me through please? i see your point. because if it changed to approved then refresh the page, it goes back to approve.

Comment: or even the text has not changed, as long as it will not be clickable afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your way of finding the `LinkButton` control is wrong. It should be like below. Again, that cell number `0` is an example. You should put the right cell number.

```
LinkButton link = row.Cells[0].FindControl("btnApprove") as LinkButton;
if(link != null)
   link.Text = "Approved";
```

Comment: thank you sir. kindly see my update please and thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that after the link button is clicked, the data in the grid is refreshed (the syntax may not be quite right, still waking up!)

The trick is to have a field in the database that you can read out again, showing this new state, that the label can operate on.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnApprove" runat="server" Text="<%=this.getText(Eval("some_DB_trigger_flag"));%>" CommandName="Approve" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and in your code behind;

```
protected string getText(int value)
{
     if(value==0) then return "Approved";
     else return "Other";
}
```